# What is the recommended jQuery and jQuery UI version?

Tags: 7, javascript

What is the recommended version of jQuery and jQuery UI that I should use on a Drupal 7.77 site?

I know the latest jQuery version is now 3.5.1, but what is the recommended version for a Drupal 7.77 site?

Comment: Use jquery_update module.

Answer (score 0):

There is usually a difference between the front end, and backend.

Some of the core displays rely on an older version of jquery.

If you install the jquery_update module, you will be able to select different versions for front end and back end - and it will tell which is the default version for Drupal Core.